# Common problems with padding/margin: how can I resolve it?

Tags: html, css

I learn that is a classic problem on `IE7` :

```
<div class="loc_main">    
    <div class="loc_cerca">
        <div class="event_cerca_item">
            Field
        </div>

        <div class="event_cerca_item">
            <input type="text" class="loc_cerca_input_hidden" />
        </div>    
    </div>    
</div>

.loc_main
{
    margin-left:30px;    
}

.loc_cerca
{
    padding-top:50px;
}

.loc_cerca_input_hidden
{
    border:1px solid #6D6E70;
    width:500px;
}

.event_cerca_item
{
    width:500px;
    float:left;
}
```

If you check on IE7 (here there is a [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/gC4gP/15/) example) you'll see that the `Input Box` inherits the `margin-left` and the `padding-top` from the div container.

In fact, if I swap `margin-left:30px;` with `padding-left:30px;` (on `.loc_main`) and `padding-top:50px;` with `margin-top:50px;` (on `.loc_cerca`) this will disappear.

It's a common IE7 bug, but I'd like to know how should I fix this troubles. Any idea? Or I just need to remember to put `margin on top/bottom` and `padding on left/right`?

Comment: You should consider using http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/ . Not sure if it'll fix your specific problem , but it's a very useful script .

Comment: Interessant script! But I'd like to know if there are other ways to fix this specific problem! Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many IE7 bugs/inconsistencies are based on whether or not certain elements have a proprietary "property" named [`hasLayout`](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html). A common way to provide it is `zoom: 1`, because it has no (relevant) side effects other than setting `hasLayout` to `true`.

Your specific example can be fixed by adding `zoom: 1` to `.loc_cerca`.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/gC4gP/17/

Comment: Wonderfull! Thank you man! Didnt know about this hasLayout ;)